# fit word2vec into training set which has data frame structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am begginer in NLP and I have some questions about a classification task. I have a data set in data frame structure which contains two columns, the first on is the texts (so strings) and the second one in the label of each test. So let's say the first column x_train and the seonc one y_train. In order to apply an MLP I could use this code

```
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 5000)

Tfidf_vect.fit(input_text)

Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(x_train)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(x_test)
```

I want to try the Word2Vec model, but I don't know how to transform my training data into number by using Word2vec. So then I could apply again the MLP model. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html),

> max_features int, default=None
>
> > If not None, build a vocabulary that
> > only consider the top max_features ordered by term frequency across
> > the corpus.

It means that based on your texts, the TfidfVectorizer will build a vocabulary that contains the top 'max_features' most frequently appeared token (word or character). For example, using a word level, set max_features = 10, it will take the 10 most commonly appeared word in your texts as its vocabulary. As for how many features you want to use, it depends on the number of words in your texts. Most common choice is 10000, though.

As for your second question, aside from Gensim's Word2Vec, you could try Keras Embedding layer. A good tutorial is posted on tensorflow website [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec#prepare_training_data_for_word2vec).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "transform my training data into number by using Word2vec"? If you are referring to obtaining an embedded representation of a given text, you can use [Gensim's Word2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_4.0.0/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html). In the documentation you will find some examples of usage of the model

Comment: I mean that my original data frame contains just text, but in order to use MLP I need numbers, thus I have to convert the training set into an embedded representation. I look throught the documentation but I didn't found something relevant.